# Swift 4: JsonSerialization of object with optional values fails

Tags: ios, swift, serialization, alamofire, swift4

I have next struct:

```
struct PatientEntity{
    let patientId: String
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let gender: String
    let birthDate: String?
    let medicalDiagnosis: String?
    let therapyDiagnosis: String?
    let therapyGoals: String?
}
```

When I try to serialize it to json in order to send it to the server side I get exception, because of Optional word on bithdate. I tried to remove optional word with next code, but no luck:

```
if let bithDate = self.patientBithDateTextField.text {
    newPatient: PatientEntity = PatientEntity(
        patientId: self.patientIDTextField.text!, 
        firstName: self.patientNameTextField.text!,
        lastName: self.patientLastNameTextField.text!, 
        gender: self.getSelectedGender(), 
        birthDate: bithDate, 
        medicalDiagnosis: nil, 
        therapyDiagnosis: nil,
        therapyGoals: nil
    )

    ...call API
}
```

My serialization code is:

```
urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
```

where parameter value is:

```
case .createPatient(let newPatient):
            return ["patient": newPatient]
```

The output print is looks like:

> The parametrs in POST string are: ["patient":
>   PatientEntity(patientId: "fff", firstName: "rrr",
>   lastName: "rrrr", gender: "Female", birthDate: Optional("2018-05-23"),
>   medicalDiagnosis: nil, therapyDiagnosis: nil, therapyGoals: nil)]

What is necessary to do in order to pass over serialisation of object right?

The exception is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write
>   (_SwiftValue)'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for a valid birthdate, optional binding is not the place to do that and I got the same error as you.  I suggest you separate out the code that retrieves input from your views. Then, test against `if bDate != nil`  as below or similar.

```
struct PatientEntity: Encodable{
    let patientId: String
    let firstName: String
    let birthDate: String?
}

var bDate: String? = "12-12-12"
var pID: String? = "2346"
var fName: String? = "gldlfk"

if bDate != nil  {
    let newPatient: PatientEntity = PatientEntity(patientId: pID!, firstName: fName!, birthDate: bDate)
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let data = try! encoder.encode(newPatient)
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)

}
```

output :

```
{"firstName":"gldlfk","birthDate":"12-12-12","patientId":"2346"}
```

Answer (score 0):

your Paramters should be an an instance of `String`, `NSNumber`, `Array`, `Dictionary`, or `NSNull` not an object of  `PatientEntity` type  so convert  `PatientEntity` to `dictionary`

so paramter should be like that

```
["patient": ["patientId": "fff", "firstName": "rrr", "lastName": "rrrr", "gender": "Female", "birthDate": Optional("2018-05-23"), "medicalDiagnosis": nil, vtherapyDiagnosis": nil, "therapyGoals": nil]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `PatientEntity`'s fields precisely correspond to what server expect, then just conform it to Encodable:

```
struct PatientEntity: Encodable {...
```

and serialize this way:

```
urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
```